# Debug windows kernel before it goes in repair mode?

Tags: windows, debugging, winapi, kernel, windbg

I am debugging windows kernel with windbg, but the problem is that when windows goes to repair mode when it detect an error during booting, and goes to repair mode, i don't attach to kernel at all to begin with.

But obviously the kernel has already loaded, and it already has detected a problem, so why am i not getting attach to it before the error is getting detected? how can i attach to it?

Note that the error is not a major one, i caused it myself for testing purposes, its because of an self signed driver in the boot driver list, and i need to attach to kernel before it detect this problem, how can i do this? I need to find which function/module is detecting this problem.

Currently i am attaching via COM pipe, the connection is between two VMs in VMware.

Comment: Read and Try bcdedit bootdebugging

Comment: @blabb the problem is that the initial break will be in winload.efi. and ntoskrnl is not loaded yet. so how can i break on ntoskrnl load or IopLoadDriver when they are not still loaded? when i try to set breakpoint it says : Bp expression 'nt!IopLoadDriver' could not be resolved,

Comment: @blabb also another problem is that doing boot debugging seems to disable driver signature enforcement : *** Windows is unable to verify the signature of
    the file \Windows\system32\drivers\test.sys.  It will be allowed to load
    because the boot debugger is enabled.

Comment: Look at [`bu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/bp--bu--bm--set-breakpoint-) for an unresolved breakpoint or [`sxe ld`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/sx--sxd--sxe--sxi--sxn--sxr--sx---set-exceptions-) to break on a module load (should work for `nt` too, but would be preferable for your own driver).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
kd> sxe ld:nt
kd> sxe ibp;.reboot
Shutdown occurred at (Wed Apr  7 02:14:59.871 2021 (UTC + 5:30))...unloading all symbol tables.
Waiting to reconnect...
BD: Boot Debugger Initialized
Connected to Windows Boot Debugger 17763 x64 target at 
Kernel Debugger connection established.  (Initial Breakpoint requested)
```

broke on nt module load

```
Windows 10 Kernel Version 17763 MP (1 procs) Free x64
Built by: 17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff800`5e204000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff800`5e61f9f0
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:00.000
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff800`5e3bf295 cc              int     3
```

stack and loading module name

```
kd> k;ds@rcx
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 fffff800`60a82de8 fffff800`5e294df5 nt!DebugService2+0x5
01 fffff800`60a82df0 fffff800`5eb19be2 nt!DbgLoadImageSymbols+0x45
02 fffff800`60a82e40 fffff800`5e76917c nt!KdInitSystem+0xaa2
03 fffff800`60a82fc0 00000000`00000000 nt!KiSystemStartup+0x16c
fffff800`60a82e70  "\SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.ex"
fffff800`60a82e90  "e"
```

bp as requested

```
kd> bp nt!IopLoadDriver
kd> bl
     0 e Disable Clear  fffff800`5e869020     0001 (0001) nt!IopLoadDriver
```

you may also need gflag +ksl

anyway sxe ld:nt breaking on ntfs.sys load a little alter and stack

```
kd> r
rax=0000000000000003 rbx=fffff80060a82200 rcx=fffff80060a82200
rdx=fffff80060a821b0 rsi=fffff8005fe00000 rdi=fffff8005d26f940
rip=fffff8005e3bf295 rsp=fffff80060a82188 rbp=fffff80060a82320
 r8=0000000000000003  r9=fffff80060a82198 r10=0000000000000000
r11=fffff8005d17dbd0 r12=0000000000000000 r13=fffff8005d1515f0
r14=0000000000000001 r15=fffff80e62170000
iopl=0         nv up ei ng nz na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0018  ds=002b  es=002b  fs=0053  gs=002b             efl=00000286
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff800`5e3bf295 cc              int     3
kd> ds @rcx
ffffbd0f`f003fa20  "Ntfs.sys"
kd> k
 # Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
00 fffff800`60a82188 fffff800`5e294df5 nt!DebugService2+0x5
01 fffff800`60a82190 fffff800`5e294d87 nt!DbgLoadImageSymbols+0x45
02 fffff800`60a821e0 fffff800`5ebbdd47 nt!DbgLoadImageSymbolsUnicode+0x2b
03 fffff800`60a82220 fffff800`5ebbc9ea nt!MiReloadBootLoadedDrivers+0x45f
04 fffff800`60a823b0 fffff800`5ebc266d nt!MiInitializeDriverImages+0x192
05 fffff800`60a82460 fffff800`5ebc228d nt!MiInitSystem+0x3a5
06 fffff800`60a82500 fffff800`5ebbb463 nt!MmInitSystem+0x89
07 fffff800`60a82530 fffff800`5e7745fb nt!InitBootProcessor+0x47b
08 fffff800`60a82750 fffff800`5e769219 nt!KiInitializeKernel+0x50b
09 fffff800`60a82a50 00000000`00000000 nt!KiSystemStartup+0x209
```

**a sample load sequence with sxe ld:***

```
kd> .lastevent
Last event: Load module winload.efi at 00000000`00844000
  debugger time: Wed Apr  7 02:35:18.275 2021 
kd> r
rax=0000000000000003 rbx=00000000001a6cc0 rcx=00000000001a6cc0
rdx=00000000001a6c60 rsi=00000000009cdb60 rdi=0000000000000000
rip=0000000000992c15 rsp=00000000001a6c38 rbp=00000000001a6d19
 r8=0000000000000003  r9=00000000001a6c98 r10=0000000000000000
r11=0000000000000000 r12=0000000000000001 r13=0000000000000002
r14=00000000001a7801 r15=0000000000000000
iopl=0         nv up di pl nz na po nc
cs=0010  ss=0000  ds=0030  es=0030  fs=0030  gs=0030 efl=00000006
winload!DebugService2+0x5:
00000000`00992c15 cc              int     3
kd> kb
 # RetAddr           : Args to Child : Call Site
00 00000000`008717d2 :  : winload!DebugService2+0x5
01 00000000`0092b413 :  : winload!DbgLoadImageSymbols+0x62
02 00000000`0092b8d0 :  : winload!BlBdStart+0x197
03 00000000`008c68ac :  : winload!BlBdInitialize+0x304
04 00000000`008c5708 :  : winload!InitializeLibrary+0x4dc
05 00000000`008451bb :  : winload!BlInitializeLibrary+0x8c
06 00000000`10137ea6 :  : winload!OslMain+0x12b
07 00000000`00000000 :  : 0x10137ea6
kd> g
Shutdown occurred at (Wed Apr  7 02:36:10.939 2021 
Waiting to reconnect...
BD: Boot Debugger Initialized
Connected to Windows Boot Debugger 17763 x64 target at 
Kernel Debugger connection established.  (Initial Breakpoint requested)


Windows Boot Debugger Kernel Version 17763 UP Free x64
Machine Name:
Primary image base = 0x00000000`00844000 Loaded module list = 0x00000000`009cdb60
System Uptime: not available
winload!DebugService2+0x5:
00000000`00992c15 cc              int     3
kd> ds@rcx
00000000`001a62a0  "winload.efi"
kd> g
Shutdown occurred at 
Waiting to reconnect...
Connected to Windows 10 17763 x64 target at 
Kernel Debugger connection established.  (Initial Breakpoint requested)

Windows 10 Kernel Version 17763 MP (1 procs) Free x64
Built by: 17763.1.amd64fre.rs5_release.180914-1434
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff802`26ea8000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff802`272c39f0
System Uptime: 0 days 0:00:00.000
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff802`27063295 cc              int     3
kd> ds@rcx
fffff802`29682e70  "\SystemRoot\system32\ntoskrnl.ex"
fffff802`29682e90  "e"
kd> g
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff802`27063295 cc              int     3
kd> ds@rcx
fffff802`29682e70  "\SystemRoot\system32\hal.dll"
kd> g
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff802`27063295 cc              int     3
kd> ds@rcx
fffff802`29682e70  "\SystemRoot\system32\kdcom.dll"
kd> g
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff802`27063295 cc              int     3
kd> ds@rcx
ffffca87`69a44f00  "mcupdate.dll"
kd> g
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff802`27063295 cc              int     3
kd> ds@rcx
ffffca87`69a44f60  "msrpc.sys"
kd> g
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff802`27063295 cc              int     3
kd> ds@rcx
ffffca87`69a44fc0  "ksecdd.sys"
kd> g
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff802`27063295 cc              int     3
kd> ds@rcx
ffffca87`69a43c80  "werkernel.sys"
kd> g
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff802`27063295 cc              int     3
kd> ds@rcx
ffffca87`69a43ce0  "CLFS.SYS"
kd> g
nt!DebugService2+0x5:
fffff802`27063295 cc              int     3
kd> ds@rcx
ffffca87`69a43d40  "tm.sys"
```

updated to address the comments

as I commented you need to know where to set the breakpoint or you need to manually trace (and bugcheck , go through not booted several times , automatic repair etc )

shown below is an initial break and a manual break on winload.efi

```
kd> .reboot
Shutdown occurred at (Wed Mar 17 23:21:19.732 2021 )...unloading all symbol tables.
Waiting to reconnect...
BD: Boot Debugger Initialized
Connected to Windows Boot Debugger 17763 x64 target at (Wed Mar 17 23:21:24.259 2021 ), ptr64 TRUE
Kernel Debugger connection established.  (Initial Breakpoint requested)

************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*f:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Symbol search path is: srv*f:\symbols*https://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
Executable search path is: 
ReadVirtual() failed in GetXStateConfiguration() first read attempt (error == 0.)
Windows Boot Debugger Kernel Version 17763 UP Free x64
Machine Name:
Primary image base = 0x00000000`00844000 Loaded module list = 0x00000000`009cdb60
System Uptime: not available
winload!DebugService2+0x5:
00000000`00992c15 cc              int     3
kd> kb
 # RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 00000000`008717d2 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`001a6d19 00000000`00000000 00000000`00992be5 : winload!DebugService2+0x5
01 00000000`0092b413 : fffff806`63301780 00000000`008440f0 00000000`009cdb60 00000000`00000000 : winload!DbgLoadImageSymbols+0x62
02 00000000`0092b8d0 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : winload!BlBdStart+0x197
03 00000000`008c68ac : 000007ff`ffffd000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`001a7000 : winload!BlBdInitialize+0x304
04 00000000`008c5708 : 00000000`895443e8 00000000`0001a014 00000000`001a6f79 00000000`00000000 : winload!InitializeLibrary+0x4dc
05 00000000`008451bb : 00000000`001a7000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : winload!BlInitializeLibrary+0x8c
06 00000000`10137ea6 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`001a7000 00000000`00000000 : winload!OslMain+0x12b
07 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`001a7000 00000000`00000000 50504120`544f4f42 : 0x10137ea6
kd> bp winload!OslpMain
kd> g
Breakpoint 0 hit
winload!OslpMain:
00000000`00846174 48895c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx
kd> kb
 # RetAddr           : Args to Child                                                           : Call Site
00 00000000`008451cc : 00000000`001a7000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : winload!OslpMain
01 00000000`10137ea6 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`001a7000 00000000`00000000 : winload!OslMain+0x13c
02 00000000`00000000 : 00000000`00000000 00000000`001a7000 00000000`00000000 50504120`544f4f42 : 0x10137ea6
```

you can check what are the calls that may get executed using uf as below

```
kd> uf /c winload!OslMain
winload!OslMain (00000000`00845090)
  winload!OslMain+0x46 (00000000`008450d6):
    call to winload!strcmp (00000000`0098a220)
  winload!OslMain+0xe0 (00000000`00845170):
    call to winload!memset (00000000`00994700)
  winload!OslMain+0x126 (00000000`008451b6):
    call to winload!BlInitializeLibrary (00000000`008c567c)
  winload!OslMain+0x137 (00000000`008451c7):
    call to winload!OslpMain (00000000`00846174)
  winload!OslMain+0x147 (00000000`008451d7):
    call to winload!BlDestroyLibrary (00000000`008c5714)
```

Comment: My `.lastevent` for `sxe ld:*` is `ntosknrl` and not `winload.efi`. I have `bcdedit /bootdebug on` and `bcdedit /bootdebug {bootmgr} on`. I am unable to break on `winload` or `bootmgr`. I am using VirtualKD currently

Comment: Fixed. Got rid of virtualkd and set up a serial COM1 pipe on the vm and connected to it manually via windbg. Now debugging bootmgr -- upvoting because this answer combined with my comment is now useful

Comment: I can't for the life of me work out how to debug winload though. `sxe ld:*` breaks on bootmgr and nt but not winload. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67136921/7194773) is my current configuration

Comment: Tried with {current} instead of {bootmgr}

Comment: Btw you either need correct symbols gflags +ksl and or single step in with t. Not any execution steps like p or g for this if you execute and dont have any proper bps it will be exevuted like a syscall from userland and will end in load of nt

Comment: {current} is the same as not specifying an identifier in the command, and the current boot entry is configured correctly as verified with bcdedit. I was under the impression that sxe ld:* would break on winload at leas that's what im reading from certain forum and blogs. I will have to try single stepping and then loading the symbols -- first i need to check whether winload.exe always has the same base address so i can use that. I'm guessing that the boot debugging functionality for bootmgr/winload is implemented in bootmgr with no kdcom.dll

Comment: https://doxygen.reactos.org/da/db4/bl_8h.html#a9ef5859fdff8fdd4a269c071cc7ddaae I'm just looking at this and i'll try putting a breakpoint on BlBdLoadImageSymbols

Comment: ermmmm what....? I just did `sxe ld:*; .reboot` on a ctrl break I did way after ibp like I had been doing and now i'm in winload. didnt even break on bootmgr. I changed nothing. Randomly worked on like the 10th time or rebooting and restarting the debugger

Comment: obviously this wasn't reproducible. Back to breaking on bootmgr and nt. You can't even set a breakpoint at the address that a function in winload might be when you're in bootmgr because it has a separate kernel debug system to winload, so you get `Shutdown occurred at (Sat Apr 17 15:40:13.374 2021 (UTC + 1:00))...unloading all symbol tables.
Waiting to reconnect...` when you press `g`, as it's its own kernel, so the debugger isn't even connected and the breakpoint doesn't go off, and then it doesn't reconnect until nt kernel loads

Comment: shut down will occur after LibraryInitialize  and after oslpMain transition to nt  and after loading of nt i edited the answer to show  a bp and break on a winload function

Comment: That's good but my problem is that the debuggee is not _connected_ (it disconnects at the end of bootmgr) and simply never connects in winload  in the first place so a breakpoint at `winload!DebugService2+0x5` for instance would be irrelevant because the debugger isn't connected to winload to deal with any breakpoint that might be set, such as  one from `sxe ld:*`, it connects however in nt before the nt debugservice breakpoint issued from `sxe ld:*`, so it is able to set the `int3` instr and handle it. On a random reboot, it connected in winload but not bootmgr. I can't work it out right now

Comment: After rebooting the host, `sxe ld:winload` is working now quite consistently for some reason, and It's showing that the debuggee is running when im on the winload start windows normally page instead of debuggee not connected. I'm not sure whether pressing ctrl break would have worked previously at that stage, because this sometimes does seem to cause the debuggee to connect when it says debugee not connected